# MongoDB - For each group select the records with the max value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In MongoDB, I'm trying to filter a collection down to only those documents that contain the most recent date by their respective group.

In traditional SQL I'd do something like:

```
Select *
From table a
Join (Select my_group, max(date) as max_date
      From table group by my_group) b 
      ON a.my_group = b.my_group AND
         a.date = b.max_date
```

With the following sample collection:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "123",
    "item1": "group 1",
    "item2": "abc",
    "item3": "abc",
    "date": "2022-01-01"
  },
  {
    "_id": "234",
    "item1": "group 1",
    "item2": "abc",
    "item3": "abc",
    "date": "2022-01-02"
  },
  {
    "_id": "345",
    "item1": "group 1",
    "item2": "abc",
    "item3": "abc",
    "date": "2022-01-02"
  },
  {
    "_id": "789",
    "item1": "group 2",
    "item2": "abc",
    "item3": "abc",
    "date": "2022-01-01"
  },
  {
    "_id": "678",
    "item1": "group 2",
    "item2": "abc",
    "item3": "abc",
    "date": "2022-01-02"
  },
  {
    "_id": "456",
    "item1": "group 2",
    "item2": "abc",
    "item3": "abc",
    "date": "2022-01-02"
  }
]
```

The expected output is:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "234",
        "date": "2022-01-02",
        "item1": "group 1",
        "item2": "abc",
        "item3": "abc"
    },
    {
        "_id": "345",
        "date": "2022-01-02",
        "item1": "group 1",
        "item2": "abc",
        "item3": "abc"
    },
    {
        "_id": "678",
        "date": "2022-01-02",
        "item1": "group 2",
        "item2": "abc",
        "item3": "abc"
    },
    {
        "_id": "456",
        "date": "2022-01-02",
        "item1": "group 2",
        "item2": "abc",
        "item3": "abc"
    }
]
```

My current best attempt is:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$item1",
      "max_date": {
        $max: "$date"
      },
      "records": {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      items: {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$records",
          "as": "records",
          "cond": {
            $eq: [
              "$$records.date",
              "$max_date"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        results: "$items"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Unfortunately, this returns the results partitioned by group. I've tried a few alternatives suggested by other posts & get a similar problem,  eg:

- [How to group and select document corresponding to max within each group in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34404834/how-to-group-and-select-document-corresponding-to-max-within-each-group-in-mongo)
- [MongoDB get rows where max value grouped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65321858/mongodb-get-rows-where-max-value-grouped)
- [Get all rows, groupped and with max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619585/get-all-rows-groupped-and-with-max-value)

Here's a [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MJeOqMpc5HW) with the query & sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close to the answer.

For the last 2 stages:

3. `$unwind` - Deconstruct the `items` array field to multiple documents.
4. `$replaceWith` - Replace the output document with `items` document.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$item1",
      "max_date": {
        $max: "$date"
      },
      "records": {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      items: {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$records",
          "as": "records",
          "cond": {
            $eq: [
              "$$records.date",
              "$max_date"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$items"
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$items"
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TkJHd_jeNDq)

---

**Bonus**

Although the query above is better, also would like to share the MongoDB query that is similar to SQL implementation.

1. `$group` - Group by `item1` and get the max value of `date`.
2. `$lookup` - Self join the collection with `item1` and `date`. And returns `items` array field.
3. `$match` - Filter the document with `items` not an empty array.
4. `$unwind` - Deconstruct the `items` array into multiple documents.
5. `$replaceWith` - Replace the output document with `items` document.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$item1",
      "max_date": {
        $max: "$date"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      let: {
        item1: "$_id",
        max_date: "$max_date"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$item1",
                    "$$item1"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$date",
                    "$$max_date"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "items"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      items: {
        $ne: []
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$items"
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$items"
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (Bonus)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bbym6DP1xpt)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for both the answer & the alternative approach. This is super informative.